# npm cache returns error Error: unexpected eof

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I try using npm cache install, I get the following error

```
 Error extracting /home/jenkins-user/cache/npm/2.14.9/28ecfa962c25c9a0d034a5eda413dc2e.tar.gz: Error: unexpected eof
```

When it tries to extract the file it tarred. Is anyone familiar with this error and fix?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution for this ?